# GetExternalLoginInfoAsync always returns null Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2b

GetExternalLoginInfoAsync always returns null.
I try integrate Azure AD into Identity.

Can I add loginProvider by hardcode, for example?

My startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddRazorPages()
         .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

It's short list, also I use custom middleware.

```
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
  });
```

I call challenge by button click

```
[HttpGet]
public ChallengeResult ExternalSignIn()
{
  var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback));
  var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties
                   (OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, redirectUrl);
  return new ChallengeResult(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, properties);
}
```

Challenge call this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
{
  //info is null
  var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(
                     info.LoginProvider, 
                     info.ProviderKey, 
                     isPersistent: false, 
                     bypassTwoFactor: false)
                     .ConfigureAwait(false);

  //other code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                options => options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
```